just want to know is this possible to compile and run test case with this code and this code fails when i try to submit it for other test cases
class Solution
{
    private:
    void helper(Node* root,vector<int>& ans){
        if(root == nullptr){
            return;
        }
        helper(root->left,ans);
        ans.push_back(root->data);
        helper(root->right,ans);
    }
    public:
    //Function to check if two trees are identical.
    bool isIdentical(Node *r1, Node *r2)
    {
        vector<int> ans1;
        vector<int> ans2;
        helper(r1,ans1);
        helper(r2,ans2);
        int n = ans1.size();
        int m = ans2.size();
        if(n != m) return false;
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            if(ans1[i] != ans2[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

in this i want to find whether the two trees are identical or not so i check their inorder traversal and store them in an array,then my task is to compare two arrays are identical or not

Is it possible to compile? Well, you can find out yourself if you just use any compiler, even an online compiler if you don't have one installed. There are even free compilers like GCC or clang. Even Visual Studio is available in a community edition.

Here's how you compare if two vectors are equal if (ans1 == ans2) You are trying too hard, vectors support == directly, you don't need to write a loop.

It's not very clear what you are asking, but I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. Try and clarify what the question actually is. If it is about compiler errors (or any kind of error), then include the errors in the question.

Generally, you can add your own main() function that creates a Solution object and calls its functions. Here you will have some problems with the Node* - where is the Node declared?

Sure.    Passing one set of test cases doesn't give a guarantee that other test cases (which might test different things) will also pass.

You're on the wrong track - if the trees are arbitrary binary trees, they are not uniquely defined by their inorder traversals.
For instance,
  2
 / 
1   

and
1
 \
  2

are far from identical but have the same inorder traversals.
Just do a recursive comparison:
bool identical_trees(const Node* a, const Node* b) {
    return (a == nullptr && b == nullptr) // Both trees are empty
        || (a != nullptr && b != nullptr  // Neither tree is empty
            && a->data == b->data
            && identical_trees(a->left, b->left)
            && identical_trees(a->right, b->right));
}

